# Whats the difference between %Q and %{} in ruby?

Tags: ruby

What are semantics of %Q and %{} in Ruby? What is difference between them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Jim Hoskins](http://jimhoskins.com/2008/10/07/ruby-percent-syntax-percent-functions/) clears it up.

> %Q is the equivalent to a double-quoted ruby string. #{expression} evaluation works just like in double-quoted strings, even if you use %Q{} as your delimiter!
>
> You can also leave off the Q and it will have the same functionality. I recommend leaving the Q in to be more clear.

Comment: It could be nice if you could post a summary or a quote from the article instead of just giving a link.

Comment: Added in the quote that's directly relevant.

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no functional difference.  Some might argue that %Q{} is a little clearer, but both are interpolated strings (just like using double quotes).

Answer (score 3):

There are in effect the same.  Both follow double-quoted string semantics